# Elixir ecto connect to an existing DB

Tags: elixir, ecto

After doing some research in the link below

https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/tree/master/examples/simple

I am a little confused about how to use ecto in elixir.

There is **always** a schema declared like

```
defmodule Weather do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "weather" do
    field :city, :string
    field :temp_lo, :integer
    field :temp_hi, :integer
    field :prcp, :float, default: 0.0
    timestamps
  end
end
```

and then in the 'Query' part

```
 def sample_query do
   query = from w in Weather,
      where: w.prcp > 0.0 or is_nil(w.prcp),
      select: w
   Simple.Repo.all(query)
   end
 end
```

ecto gona form a query using **the schema declared in Weather**

My question is that **I just want to connect to an existing database 'TESTDB' and doing some SELECT, I don't need any new schmema to do my work**. Is it possible to do it in ecto please?

When I create my own query like

```
query = from w in tenant
```

after I input the command `$ mix do deps.get, compile`

the error tells me `function tenant/0 undefined`

`tenant` is not function, it just a table in `TESTDB` that I didn't declare anywhere

I think I just lost myself in ecto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the schema for your table whether you create it using `Ecto` or not. I don't think there's currently an option to do this automatically. So for example you can have something like:

```
defmodule Tenant do
  use Ecto.Model

  schema "tenant" do
    field :id, :integer
    field :name, :string
    # and so on depending on the columns in your table
  end
end
```

And then do `query = from w in Tenant, select: w`

Comment: I just figured out when i do a `select` query, the fields declared in the schema are retrieved

Answer (score 11):

You can query any table in the database by passing a string:

```
from p in "posts", where: p.id > 0
```

In such cases, you don't need to define any schema, you can just query the table directly. Finally, you can also do a SQL query directly:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(YourRepo, "SELECT $1", [1])
```

But then you lose most of the benefits Ecto gives you.

Comment: This is informative!! I also figured out if I want to select multiple fields, I need to do it like `select: {p.id, p.uuid}`

Comment: It seems that it does not work. I get the following error message: `Please specify a model or specify exactly which fields from "l0" you desire in query:`.

Comment: I tried to add `select: p.*` and it didn't work. Is it possible to list all fields without enumerating them ?